# Amend all values in an Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a lab for my Programming I class where we need to design a program that uses an ArrayList of resistances to calculate the total resistance of a parallel and series circuit. For the parallel circuit, I need to change every item in the ArrayList to its reciprocal (1/item). I got to this point and cannot seem to find why this is wrong and a possible way around it. Thanks.

**the error I get is "The method get(int) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (double)" for the line " resistances = 1 / resistances.get(index);" **

-businesslogic class-

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
* The class Circuit gathers the resistances of a user-defined number of
* resistors for a user-defined type of circuit and displays the total
* resistance of the circuit for the main method of the Presentation class.
*/

public class Circuit {

    private double arrayListSize;

    public double n;

    public double sum;

    public double finalSum;

    public ArrayList<Double> resistances = new ArrayList<Double>();

    /**
     * @param initialPop
     *      user-defined initial population
     */
    public final void setArraySize(final double alSize) {
        arrayListSize = alSize;
    }

    public final double getArraySize() {
        return arrayListSize;
    }

    public final void setResistors(double alResistances) {
        for (n = 0; n < getArraySize(); n++) {
            resistances.add(alResistances);
        }
    }

    public  ArrayList<Double> getResistors() {
        return resistances;
    }

    public final void setPResistance(ArrayList<Double> resistances) {
        for (double index : resistances) {
            resistances = 1 / resistances.get(index);
        }
        sum = 0;
        for (double i : resistances) {
            sum =sum + i;
        }
        double finalSum = 1 / sum;

    }

    public final double getPResistance() {
        return finalSum;
    }
}
```

-presentation class-

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
* The Class Presentation
*/
public class Presentation {

    /**
    * The main class uses the Circuit class and user input 
    * to calculate the total resistance of a circuit.
    * 
    * @param args
    *            command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Circuit resistanceTotal = new Circuit();

        System.out.println("This program will calculate the"
                + " total resistance of either a parallel or "
                + " a series circuit.\n");

        System.out.println("Would you like to calculate the"
                + " resistance of a parallel circuit (1) or a"
                + " series circuit (2)?");
        int userChoice = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("How many resistors are there in the circuit?");
        resistanceTotal.setArraySize(keyboard.nextDouble());

        System.out.println("Enter resistance of resistor #" + (resistanceTotal.n + 1));
        resistanceTotal.setResistors(keyboard.nextDouble());
        resistanceTotal.getResistors();

        if (userChoice == 1) {
            resistanceTotal.setPResistance(resistanceTotal.getResistors());
            resistanceTotal.getPResistance();
        }

        if (userChoice != 1 & userChoice != 2) {
            System.out.println("You must enter 1 or 2!!!");
        }
        keyboard.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Post any exceptions or incorrect output please

Comment: **the error I get is "The method get(int) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (double)" for the line " resistances = 1 / resistances.get(index);" **

Comment: Okay, so you want each value in the array list replaced with its reciprocal value?

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in this the `setPResistance` method. The method `arrayList.get(i)` takes a `int` value as a parameter, and you passed it the actual value of the position, which is a `double`.

To replace each item in the arraylist to its reciprocal, change the method like so:

```
public final void setPResistance(ArrayList<Double> resistances) {
    for (int c = 0; c < resistances.size(); c++) {
        resistances.set(c, 1/resistances.get(c));
    }
}
```

Java docs on the `set(int index, Double element)` method:

> Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the
>   specified element.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted